# Angular firebase database list elements to be observables

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The problem is that I have queried a list from @angular/fire database as:

```
constructor(private afdb:AngularFireDatabase){}

getList(){
   return this.getListSnapShot()
       .pipe(map(items=>{
          return itemsArray.map(item=>{
                let category$=this.getCategory(item.categoryId);
                let value=item;
                return {...item,category$:category$};
                    })     
          }));
}


getCategory(key:string){
     return this.afdb.object(`category/${key}`).valueChanges();
}

getListSnapShot(){
    return this.db.list(`items`).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(items => {
         return items.map(x=>{
                  let value={ ...x.payload.val(), _id: x.payload.key };
                  return value;
                })
    }))
}
```

Now the problem is when I try of `.map()` this itemsArray and add observable as `category$` in the object -> `return {...item,category$:category$};`. The return type of function becomes `Observable<any>` instead of `Observable<any[]>` and thus produced error.

Here function `getListSnapShot()` is used to get the list with its keys (generated by firebase database).

`payload.val()` contains the key of category (to be fetched by another function) inside the items list. This key is to be used to fetch the actual category object from firebase database.

Comment: I dont know the answer to why its observable<any> and not any[]. but I don't think you would get an error from an observable that's really generic. try forcing the type by writing "as observable<any[]> after itemsArray.map(). that might force it

Comment: another thing that I dont understand is why do you use pipe() in succession I don't see a reason for that. I think your first pipe() method can do everything and be less confusing.

Comment: just one more thing, friendly advice. unless absolutely necessary I don't think you should make separate calls for each category you have. depending on the size of your list, you can have a crazy amount of listeners.